# mongoDB Atlas ♥︎ Sailsjs (waterline sails-mongo adapter)

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, mongodb-atlas, sails-mongo

i just created a [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/pricing) account.

I'm using sails with waterline [sails-mongo](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo) adapter

but I can't manage to connect via my app.

- Everything is up to date.
- I can connect to any other DB (localhost, digitalocean server, ...)
- I can also connect to that MongoDB Atlas Database via their tool (MongoDB Compass) and via shell with the mongo cmd

but it seems like sails-mongo is just not working with that db, which requires a very up-to-date mongo version

Is someone else using MDB Atlas && sailsjs ?
(I thought about refactoring my app, but it's starting to be huuge and it just seems impossible to use the "mongodb" adapter)

Versions :
 - node : 6.3.1
 - npm : 3.10.6
 - mongo (shell) : 3.4.2
 - sails-mongo npm module : sails-mongo@0.12.2

Comment: What error do you have? Please post some code, maybe read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hey people thanks to your tips and SailsJS team I was able to figure out a few things that can help you fix this issue (I was able to):

- Update your sails-mongo to v0.12.3 `npm install sails-mongo@0.12.3 --save`
- Update sails-mongo's mongodb dependency to v2.2.25. You can do this editing package.json. That version includes a fix for replicaSets connections: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/commit/915d5c8a765151fb14942445a92d92a0e9e9c942#diff-88dc7475eedf918122374be6d7c2c151R12
- Make sure that the mongodb's mongodb-core version is at least v2.1.9.
- Now I went directly and created my connection like this:

  `{
      adapter: 'sails-mongo', 
      url: 'mongodb://user:pass@server-1.mongodb.net:27017,server-2.mongodb.net:27017,server-3.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=server-&authSource=admin', 
      ssl: true
  }`

  Yes, you need to add the *ssl* parameter again.

By looking at the sails v1.0 code, lost of this things will be fixed by that update ;) Thanks SailsJS Team!

Comment: you can also update sails-mongo to the latest beta version by doing `npm install sails-mongo@beta`

Comment: After migrating from **mLab** to ***Atlas*** the only thing I was missing was the `ssl: true` part. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 4):

> it seems like sails-mongo is just not working with that db, which requires a very up-to-date mongo version

You hit the nail on the head -- the current sails-mongo adapter for Sails v0.12.x uses a version of the native MongoDB driver that doesn't support all the features required to work with Atlas (e.g. `authSource`).  See [this issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4015) on Github.

We're finishing up the last bits on the `sails-mongo` adapter for Sails 1.0, which supports the latest options and has been tested successfully with Atlas, so now might be a good time to start preparing to [upgrade to version 1.0](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/1.0/upgrading/To1.0.md).  After Sails 1.0 is released we'll only be doing bug fixes and security patches to modules that work with v0.12.x.

Comment: Hey Sgress454, thank you for your answer. I guess I'll need to refactor anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the connection is timing out. Step one would be to check your configuration, is it correctly populated with this format in [config/connections.js](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/anatomy/config/connections.js)?

```
  // MongoDB is the leading NoSQL database.
  // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB
  //
  // Run:
  // npm install sails-mongo
  //
  someMongodbServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    // user: 'username',
    // password: 'password',
    // database: 'your_mongo_db_name_here'
  },
```

If it's not your configuration, it's likely an incompatibility with your version of sails, sails-mongo, or Mongo DB. Which versions of these are you running?

Comment: Hey Solumos, Thank you for your time and answer. my config looks like someMongodbServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    url: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
  }, see ref : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/ But, I think you're right, that's what I have in mind. sails-mongo is not enough up to date to work with mongoDB Atlas

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can select the version of mongoDB you want to be installed on your cluster with Atlas. I think the only caveat to that is if you go with the free tier M0 I think its called which forces you on to the fixed version, wiresomething or other.